# How to remove white pixels from Binary image using Morphological Operators?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, binary-image

I am working with images of rocks. Here I have to segment them. I get a depth image as input.

After thresholding the image, there are some white pixels which I tried to remove but to no avail.

The methods I have used : 
1. Bilateral Filter (not a morphological operator)
2. Closing
3. Erosion

The result are shown in the images below.

My task is to remove those white pixels INSIDE THE ROCKS using morphological operations. If the white pixels are not removed it affects my algorithm later(distance transform).

Is there a way using only morphological operations?If not, is there any other way?

## 1.Bilateral Filter

[image: Bilateral Filter]

## 2.Closing

[image: Closing]

## 3.Erosion

[image: Erosion]

## 4.Original Depth Image

[image: Depth Image]

Comment: Please provide the original image separate .

Comment: @Christoffer: I have added the original image to the question

Comment: What are the rocks? I just see what looks like a cloud in that range image. What is the expected output?

Comment: It is not the original image, it is a screenshot image, please put the original image.